# What is a term used to describe something that is essentially the same thing but serves a different function?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was looking for a general term to describe vernacular houses that are not used as dwellings, but for different functions (granaries, etc.). I used 'auxiliary houses' but I didn't want to downgrade them to something as such.

Comment: Your question title is at odds with your question body.

Comment: repurposed house ? "repurpose : adapt for use in a different purpose."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Outbuilding:** a building (such as a stable or a woodshed) separate from
>   but accessory to a main house
>   (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outbuilding).

I've also seen them called "service buildings" in a more modern setting.

(Not to be confused with "outhouse", which is an outdoor toilet)

Comment: Actually, *outhouse* is a synonym for *outbuilding*, was used for hundreds of years, and only in the 19th century gained the secondary, more specific meaning. Basically it was used as a euphemism, because *privy* wasn't vague enough.